# Pytorch won't run on deep-learning-vm "Found no NVIDIA driver on your system"

Tags: pytorch, nvidia

I did create a new conda environment to run my code from. But I get the following error:

```py
AssertionError: 
Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you
have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
> /opt/conda/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py(51)_check_driver()
     49         if torch._C._cuda_getDriverVersion() == 0:
     50             # found no NVIDIA driver on the system
---> 51             raise AssertionError("""
     52 Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you
     53 have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: If you are using pytorch, please provide the versions (python, pytorch, cuda, nvidia driver) and your GPU information.